# How to create a Drupal menu link to a civicrm contact profile

Tags: contacts, checksum, contact-view

I would like to create a drupal menu link for a logged in user. I have added `civicrm/contact/view`, which seems to only work when the contact profile was viewed once.  Otherwise keep getting message `We could not find a contact id`. Can anyone have a quick solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module and [Civicrm token](https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/guanhuan-2356699/-/archive/7.x-1.x/guanhuan-2356699-7.x-1.x.zip) module to create link in drupal module.

```
civicrm/contact/view?cid=[civi:contact_ID]&reset=1
```

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Try git cloning  https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/guanhuan-2356699.git